# How many columns can a SQL data set contain?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A table has a maximum number of columns, as well as a maximum row size. This has to do with the way the data is stored on disk.

What about the result of a query or stored procedure - a data set. Is there a limit on the number of columns that this can contain?

Answer (score 1):

Columns per SELECT statement is 4096
See: [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.100).aspx)